# get dynamic csrf token

Tags: laravel, csrf, csrf-protection

I have function that generate a form from a model.

**Category Model:**

```
public static function generateForm()
{
    $output = '';

    $output .= '<form action="/category" method="post">
                '. csrf_field() .'
                <input type="text">
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="">                      
            </form>';
    return $output;
}
```

It's not working.
In my ***view** it's showing the hidden input token but doesn't get any value.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean by "it's showing the hidden input token but doesn't get any value"?

Comment: <input type="hidden" name="_token" value=""> no value in my html

Answer (score 0):

You can pass `csrf_token` dynamically from view to that function html.

Here is the example of that:-

**Category.php**

```
public static function generateForm($token)
{
    $output = '';

    $output .= '<form action="/category" method="post">
                <input type="hidden" name="csrf_token" value="'.$token.'">
                <input type="text">
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="">                      
            </form>';
    return $output;
}
```

Now you need to pass only parameter to this function where you are calling. Like this:-

**view.blade.php**

```
{{ $category->generateForm(csrf_token()) }}
```

Comment: It is the same as before.

Comment: @kundefine can you attach your screenshot with inspect element of your form?

Answer (score -1):

Please make sure APP_KEY in .env file is not blank. If it is blank then run "php artisan key:generate" to generate that. After setting APP_KEY all will work fine.

Comment: if the `APP_KEY` is empty then laravel would throw an error right away and whole application will not work

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
 public static function generateForm() {

        $output = '<form action="/category" method="post">'.
                               csrf_field().
                              '<input type="text">
                              <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="">                      
                          </form>';
        return $output;
    }
```